# How to create multiple adsets using facebook marketing api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to target multiple lat-long(more than 200). There is a option of multiple ad sets in Facebook power editor but how to achieve this with Facebook Marketing API using curl. After doing a lot of research found this

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign

but it's just showing multiple adsets information and except this I did not found any other explanation on facebook marketing api doc to create an ad using multiple ad sets.

Answer (score 0):

Couldnt comment under 50 :)

Here is your solution :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/buying-api/targeting/

EDIT: if you want to create multiple ads this video will help you :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pq1y_Ze-0g8

if you want to target multiple with lat and long.

```
use FacebookAds\Object\TargetingSearch;
use FacebookAds\Object\Search\TargetingSearchTypes;

$result = TargetingSearch::search(
  TargetingSearchTypes::GEOLOCATION,
  null,
  'un',
  array(
    'location_types' => array('country'),
  ));
```

for more info :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-search/

Comment: that's what i want to apply using facebook marketing api.https://medium.com/@mihhovil/facebook-ads-manager-update-creating-multiple-ad-sets-at-once-3edc30a0c277

Comment: So you want to create multiple ad-set or target ?

Comment: I want to create multiple adsets on a single ad if you will read the documentation. we can't add custom locations more than 200 so i need to create multiple adsets for that ad and divide the budget according to the no. of custom locations for each adset